# Why is the angle between the radial velocities at two instants the same as the angle between the tangential velocities at those same instants?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

[image: From the book An Introduction to Mechanics by D. Kleppner and R. Kolenkow.]

While it is clear that the angle between $v_r$ and $v_r +  \Delta v_r$ is $\Delta \theta$, I cannot see a clear geometric reason as to why the angle between $v_t$ and $v_t +  \Delta v_t$ must also be $\Delta \theta$.

The book by Kleppner and Kolenkow uses this to argue that $\Delta v_t \approx v_r \Delta \theta$ and in the limit in which $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$ , $\frac{d v_t}{dt} = v_t \dot{\theta} = r\dot{\theta}^2 $.

Comment: What is the shape of the path? Elliptical, parabolic, hyperbolic, ovoid?

Comment: Completely arbitrary curve, as far as the book is concerned. I think we can safely assume it has continuous first and second derivatives.

Comment: What do "radial" and "tangential" mean in this context? I guess that they denote two local directions with a 90° angle between them, one pointing away from the "center", the other along the tangent of a circle around the "center". Then the assertion makes sense.

Comment: No radial as in the 'r-hat' unit vector in polar coordinates and tangential as in tangent to the curve (like velocity to the path curve). Radial is not the normal direction as in perpendicular to the tangent, but in the direction of the vector going outward from the origin to the point.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct, this is on p37, also this book is a classic, so many people have it, referencing it properly would speed things up.

First, I'm assuming that Vt is the component of velocity tangent to the f(x) that is your objects position, and Vr, well is just radial velocity.

Before diving in, I want you to show how your understanding is wrong of the problem on hand. Vr is not always perpendicular to tangent of a curve, rather the normal to that curve is that, radial is meant as anything to do with respect to the center of one's coordinate system, be it distance, velocity or others. Now you might say that the tangent is to the curve, rather than the conventional meaning (theta direction in the polar coordinates you mentioned).

Let's assume that there is a strait line, say with equation x = const., so if Vt is tangent to the line of motion, it's always the same.

So let's assume that the tangential component, is in fact the component perpendicular to the radial velocity, so the overall speed is root square of the sum of 2 velocities, written as:

$$V(total)^2 = Vr^2  +  Vt^2$$

Now, if you think of your tangent and radial velocity like the figure below, everything will fall into place:

[image]

Comment: I understand well that the radial direction is not the normal direction. I don't think we can assume that the tangential component is perpendicular to the radial one since the diagram in the text clearly seems to suggest otherwise.

Comment: I think I got your point and I may have actually found an erratum. The diagram is misleading since the so called tangential velocity is actually in the theta-hat direction (normal to the radial r-hat) and not tangent to the path as suggested. This is seen easily by reminding oneself that the net velocity is supposed to be tangential to the curve and not generally any of its components.

Comment: @ambrishabhijatya True, a more intuitive approach in terms of algebraic expressions would also be to also notice that the equation for centripetal force  is already assuming $$Vt = r*d(θ)/dt$$, a hint that this is the case, also if one vector changing by delta θ results in another related vector to also differ by delta θ as well, means they are constant w.r.t each other in terms of their angle.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is obviously true for motion in a circle.  For any short arc (swept out in a short time) a center of curvature can be found so that the arc can be considered part of a circle.

Comment: Would you say that the first diagram is misleading since the radial and tangential components are shown to not be perpendicular?

Comment: The proposition is said to be true in the limit as Δt approaches zero.  The diagram is misleading since the indicated (r) is not from the center of curvature.